# How and why does this variable substitution in this integral work?

Tags: calculus, substitution

$$\int_{-5}^5  \frac{1}{1+2^{\arctan(x)}} dx$$

In the solution of this example authors do such thing:

$$\int_{-5}^5  \frac{1}{1+2^{\arctan(x)}} dx = [x = -t; dx = -dt; t = -x] = \int_5^{-5}  \frac{-1}{1+2^{-{\arctan(t)}}} dt = \int_{-5}^5  \frac{1}{1+2^{-{\arctan(x)}}} dx$$

Then we just sum this two integrals, everything is great, the **answer is 5**.
But I can't understand how we came to the final integral. If I just replace back t, I will get the first integral. Why does this last step work?

Comment: The last step in the chain of shown equations is the fact that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = -\int_b^a f(x) dx$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$  \int_5^{-5}  \frac{-1}{1+2^{-{\arctan(t)}}} dt\\=\int_{-5}^5  \frac{1}{1+2^{-{\arctan(t)}}} dt\\= \int_{-5}^5  \frac{1}{1+2^{-{\arctan(x)}}} dx$$

That last step (renaming $t$ to $x$) works because $t$ and $x$ here are just [dummy variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4391499/21813).

After all, $$\int_0^\pi \sin(x)\,\mathrm dx=2=\int_0^\pi\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

(On the other hand, $\large\int \sin(x)\,\mathrm dx=-\cos(x)\ne-\cos(\theta)=\int\sin(\theta)\,\mathrm d\theta.)$